# How C++ set insert work with custom comparator

Tags: c++, c++11

I am wring one set of pointers

```
class CLwObj {
private:
string name ;
int type ;

public:
CLwObj() {}
CLwObj(string val, int typ) { name =val ; type = typ; }

string getName() { return name; }
int getType() { return type; }
};

class CLwObjCompare
{
    public:
    bool operator () (CLwObj* obj1, CLwObj* obj2) const
    {
        bool val =  ((obj1->getName().compare(obj2->getName()) < 0) ) ;
        return val;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    set<CLwObj*, CLwObjCompare> myset ;

    CLwObj *obj1 = new CLwObj("hello", 1);
    CLwObj *obj2 = new CLwObj("kello", 1);
    CLwObj *obj3 = new CLwObj("hello", 1);

    myset.insert(obj1);
    myset.insert(obj2);
    myset.insert(obj3);
    return 0;
}
```

Please explain how insert work with custom comparator , i am getting only two entry since two having same name.

I thought compare function only decided orders.
All object will have different address so 3 entry should be there .

Comment: Use `multiset` if you need multiple (ordered) entries for the same key.

Comment: That's how `set` is supposed to work - `insert(obj3)` fails to insert because there is already an object with that key

Comment: What is your actual question - how to use a comparator, or why your code only inserts two objects?

Comment: How set knows name is the key. I am inserting address.

Comment: @AvinashKumar You passed the comparer `CLwObjCompare`, set use that comparer to determine if 2 object is the same. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set `Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare concept, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a) ` By the way, can you tell us why you chose pointer as the element? C++ is not Java

Comment: Your comparator says the two are the same because neither is less than the other

Comment: @Danh Ok got the point, Thanks !! " By the way, can you tell us why you chose pointer as the element? C++ is not Java " what is means ?

Comment: @AvinashKumar Why don't just `std::set<CLwObj, SomeComparer>`

Comment: @Danh then all the object will be destroyed once i am out of code block .

Comment: @AvinashKumar Yes, why do you want to keep it but have no access to it? Why don't you free it? Have you heard about memory leak?

Comment: @Danh , ii is just an example , in actual code i am passing set to other function . Could you suggest me some comparator which will uniqify all three object   CLwObj("hello",1) , CLwObj("hello",2) , CLwObj("meelo",1)

Comment: @AvinashKumar If you store the `CLwObj` in the set, then the set is its owner and it will manage these object lifetime. For the 2nd question, `return name < rhs.name && id < rhs.id;`

Comment: @Danh this comparison is not working . for first part , how will remove the memory then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98789/discussion-between-danh-and-avinash-kumar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/ (on the `Compare` template argument):

> The set object uses this expression to determine both the order the elements follow in the container **and whether two element keys are equivalent** (by comparing them reflexively: they are equivalent if !comp(a,b) && !comp(b,a)). No two elements in a set container can be equivalent.
> This can be a function pointer or a function object (see constructor for an example).

From the [standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard), §23.2.4:

> 2. Each associative container is parameterized on Key and an ordering
>    relation Compare that induces a strict weak ordering (25.4) on
>    elements of Key. In addition, map and multimap associate an arbitrary
>    mapped type T with the Key. The object of type Compare is called the
>    comparison object of a container.
> 3. The phrase “equivalence of keys”
>    means the equivalence relation imposed by the comparison and not the
>    operator== on keys. That is, two keys k1 and k2 are considered to be
>    equivalent if for the comparison object comp, comp(k1, k2) == false &&
>    comp(k2, k1) == false. For any two keys k1 and k2 in the same
>    container, calling comp(k1, k2) shall always return the same value.

And §23.4.6.1 (emphasis is mine):

> 2. A set satisfies all of the requirements of a container, of a reversible container (23.2), **of an associative
>    container (23.2.4)**, and of an allocator-aware container (Table 99).

Answer (score 0):

**Copy from comment to continue discussion**

You passed the comparer `CLwObjCompare`, `set` use that comparer to determine if 2 object is the same.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

> Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare concept, uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In imprecise terms, two objects a and b are considered equivalent (not unique) if neither compares less than the other: !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)

**Continue in discussion**

Here below is my suggestion:

```
class CLwObj {
private:
    string name ;
    int type ;

public:
    CLwObj() {}
    CLwObj(string val, int typ) { name =val ; type = typ; }

    string getName() const { return name; }
    int getType() const { return type; }
};

class CLwObjCompare
{
public:
    bool operator () (const CLwObj& obj1, const CLwObj& obj2) const
    {
        return lhs.getName() < rhs.getName() && lhs.getType() < rhs.getType();
    }
};

int main ()
{
    set<CLwObj, CLwObjCompare> myset ;

    myset.emplace("hello", 1);
    myset.emplace("kello", 1);
    myset.emplace("hello", 2);
    return 0;
}
```